# Render openCTM files on android (especially flutter)

Tags: flutter

I'm currently developing an App in Flutter which i need to display 3D models. I know. Flutter is, at least at the moment, not the best choice (or shouldn't be even a choice) to build 3d apps but unfortunately i didn't know this when i started developing. I managed to render a simple '.obj' file with a simple engine I found on the internet:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/a-simple-3d-engine-in-flutter-cc4a7edc943e

Now my problem:

My app needs to contain multiple hundred 3D models so I need to reduce the app's size. I experimented with openCTM to compress my '.obj' models and got a good result.
Now i want to display these '.ctm' files in my app. And thats the point where I got stuck.

I've researched for days if there's a sample or a tutorial to solve my problem but I haven't found one.

I've read the official openCTM documents and found openCtm reader ported to javascript (https://github.com/jcmellado/js-openctm) and dart (https://github.com/nelsonsilva/dart-openctm). And now I dont know where to begin. 
I guess I need to, if my problem is solvable in flutter, modify the engine im currently using and add the openCTM reading part to it.

I hope that anyone of you can help me with my problem. Maybe even solved it already. Furthermore I hope I explained my problem clear enough.

If you can provide a native solution it would helpful, too.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Will a solution in (embedded) browser work for you? Like it is implemented in WASM-based [MeshInspector](https://demo.meshinspector.com/), the page requires simple and free registration by email and later can show you any openCTM file.